# Unexpected token (FIELD_NAME), expected END_OBJECT: expected closing END_OBJECT after type information and deserialized value

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have my API which takes a FileImportInput and this has the following model

```
        FileImportInput {
    
      private String importType;
      private String resourceUri;
    
      @JsonProperty("settings")
      private MriImportRequest settings;
    }
```

This MriImportRequest is the base class with the following fields

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "settings")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonSubTypes({
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MriExcelImportRequest.class, name = "sheets"),
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MriTextFileImportRequest.class, name = "files")
    })

   
 public class MriImportRequest {
      private int folderId;
      private String locale;
      private String currency;
    }
```

Below are other two classes with the following definitions.

```
@JsonTypeName("files")
public class MriTextFileImportRequest extends MriImportRequest {

  private int accountsFileId;
  private int locationsFileId;
  private int reinsuranceFileId;
  private int mappingFileId;
}
```

The other class is as follows

```
@JsonTypeName("sheets")
public class MriExcelImportRequest extends MriImportRequest {
  private int accountsSheetIndex;
  private int locationsSheetIndex;
  private int reinsuranceSheetIndex;
  private int mappingFileIndex;}
```

The request JSON is below, When i make a request, Unrecognized field "files"  I am not sure whats missing. The request Json is below

```
{
    "importType": "mri",
    "resourceUri": "riskdata/v1/exposuresets/es1/exposures/sdfd-2232-skdj-3434/portfolios/12",
    "settings": {
        "files": {
            "accountsFileId": 5387,
            "locationsFileId": 5388,
            "reinsuranceFileId": 5389,
            "mappingFileId": 5390
        },
        "folderId": 1686,
        "currency": "USD",
        "locale": "US"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`JsonTypeInfo.As#WRAPPER_OBJECT`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#WRAPPER_OBJECT) is used for serialization while you are trying to deserialize your json, so no use for it in this case. Instead you can use the [`JsonTypeInfo.Id#DEDUCTION`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#DEDUCTION) to deduce types based on the fields available (in this case if *files* property is available the value will be automatically deserialized to the `MriTextFileImportRequest` subclass:

```
@Data
public class FileImportInput {

    private String importType;
    private String resourceUri;
    @JsonProperty("settings")
    private MriImportRequest settings;
}

@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MriTextFileImportRequest.class)
})
public class MriImportRequest {

    private int folderId;
    private String locale;
    private String currency;
}

@Data
public class MriTextFileImportRequest extends MriImportRequest {
    private Files files;
}

@Data
public class Files {

    private int accountsFileId;
    private int locationsFileId;
    private int reinsuranceFileId;
    private int mappingFileId;
}
```

Then the code below prints the json input file:

```
FileImportInput fileImportInput = mapper.readValue(json, FileImportInput.class);
//ok it prints the input json file
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(fileImportInput));
```